# Pandas Dataframe Grouping data on weekly basis - Plotly Library

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I have a Pandas data frame that looks like this-

> **ID | Published Date   |  Topic**
>
> 1   |2020-03-11        |  Law
>
> 2    |2020-03-16       |  Housing
>
> 3    |2020-03-18       |  Housing
>
> 4     |2020-04-06       |  Law
>
> 5     |2020-04-08       |  Tax

`Published Date`is a datetime64[ns] column.

I want to show the **Volume of Publication per week for each Topic** (Count of weekly Publications grouped by Topics) in a Plotly Time Series Line Graph.
I am not sure I should group the data before using Plotly or Plotly has a feature that can help me do so.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your `Published Date` column as a DateTime column, you can do the following:

```py
# create new column with week-of-year value
df['Week'] = df['Published Date'].dt.week
# groupby week + topic (or vise-versa)
gb = df.groupby(['Week', 'Topic']
volume = gb.size()
```

This will give you a final DataFrame showing you the size (number of rows per group) of each week-topic grouping.

If your column is not in DateTime format, simply use `pd.to_datetime` on the column to convert it [(docs)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).